# How are Threads allocated to handle request ? especially If request are about 10K per second

Tags: spring, multithreading, web, model-view-controller, threadpool

I have been asked in an interview that, what kind of optimization you'll perform to handle about 10K request per second.
What kind of strategy you'll comply while developing controllers.